# How many is "$n$"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

A committee contains $n$ members. If total number of subcommittees with $3$ members is $56$, what is $n$?

I got $8$ because I tried out every single answer from multiple choice. However, I was wondering if there is a easier way to do this

Comment: You need Pascal's triangle, the answer lies in $8C3$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $C(n,3) = 56,
n(n-1)(n-2) = 56 \times 3!$

and use the fact prime factorization of $56*3!$ is $ (2^4)\times(3^1)\times(7^1) $

Also $n(n-1)(n-2) = 6*7*8$.

Do some calculations to find that $n$ to be $8$.

Comment: The question was about providing an "easier way", not a "harder way".

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mind cubes (or cube roots), then

$$ (n-2)^3\ <\,\ 6\cdot\binom n3\ <\,\ (n-1)^3 $$

would be the key.

E.g.
$$ 6^3 = 216\,\ <\,\ 6\cdot 56 = 336\,\ <\,\ 343 = 7^3 $$

hence the requested $\ n\ $ is $\ n=8$.

Explicitly:

$$ n\ =\ \sqrt[3]{\,\left\lceil6\cdot\binom n3\right\rceil + 1} $$